# Move Bootstrap 3rd column to top of row after responding to breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this 3-column row in Bootstrap that looks like this:

[image]

At some break point, it flips vertical and becomes ordered top to bottom with the ABC list showing last as expected. I would like to know if there's a feature (like a data attribute) of Bootstrap that will move the ABC list of the third column to the vertical top of the row.. maybe an index or something implemented by Bootstrap. If not, this is the HTML snippet in question - is the same result achievable with CSS?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Weekly News</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel body
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Daily Events</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel body
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group col-md-4">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">A</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">B</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">C</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*` to reorder your columns.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">A</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">B</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">C</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Weekly News</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel body
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Daily Events</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel body
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqt3bo8r/1/)**

Bootstrap link: **[Column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)**

Comment: Thanks - perfect answer with the additional links below.